# Change button title text wont work

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to change the UIButton title text, but it doesn't work. I have it in a `UITableView`. This is what it looks like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let imageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StoryCell
        let videoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("videoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StoryCell
        let blankCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("blankCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StoryCell

        if (userFile[indexPath.item].url!.rangeOfString(".jpeg") != nil) {
            print("imageCell: \(userFile[indexPath.row].url)")

            imageCell.viewstoryButton.setTitle("Vis bildeeee - \(self.createdAt[indexPath.row].timeAgo)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            imageCell.viewstoryButton.titleLabel?.textColor  = UIColor.redColor()

            return imageCell
        }
        if (userFile[indexPath.row].url!.rangeOfString(".mp4") != nil) {
            print("videoCell: \(userFile[indexPath.row].url)")

            videoCell.viewstoryButton.setTitle("Vis video - \(self.createdAt[indexPath.row].timeAgo)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            return videoCell
        }
        else{
            print("blankCell")
            return blankCell
        }

    }
```

And I have 3 prototype cells: `imageCell`, `videoCell` and `blankCell`.

They are all connected to `StoryCell`, and the buttons will appear, but the text or color doesn't change. Any ideas?

Comment: these buttons are visible in cell when run application? and have you check that your if block calls or not?

Comment: Setup breakpoints to see if those lines are called. Also is it possible that reloadData may be needed with the way your code flows?

Comment: @Lion Yes, they are visible - and yes the if block calls, because it print out both from imageCell and videoCell - But something is weird. Is you see on this column in Parse here: http://i63.tinypic.com/1zd7lzc.jpg, it contains two images and one video, but when i run my application, it shows up two table view video cells, and one image cell.. Any clues?

Comment: Typo (`indexPath.item`)?

Comment: it should be indexPath.row! good catch @vadian

Comment: ... and create the cells in their scope. At the moment you're creating **always** two useless cells every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called.

Comment: @vadian I fixed it. Just made a UICollectionView instead - working now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your buttons are Also Connected to your Swift file as an Outlet

Comment: The buttons are added in another Cocoa class for the cell: `StoryCell.swift`

Comment: in Story Cell.Swift add Outlets  for Buttons ..
and in cellForRowAtIndexPath implement the changing title

Answer (score 0):

As explain to the official [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:) the correct syntax is:

> setTitle(_ title: String?,
>            forState state: UIControlState)

And for titleLabel the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel) say:

> titleLabel: UILabel? { get }

so, your syntax code was correct.

You can check if **reloadData**() is called and also if your **IBOutlet** buttons are correctly connected to the custom cell library called "StoryCell"

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var imageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StoryCell
        if imageCell == nil {
            imageCell = StoryCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: ("imageCell"))
        }

        var videoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("videoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StoryCell
        if videoCell == nil {
            videoCell = StoryCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: ("videoCell"))
        }

        var blankCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("blankCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StoryCell
        if blankCell == nil {
            blankCell = StoryCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: ("blankCell"))
        }        

        if (userFile[indexPath.item].url!.rangeOfString(".jpeg") != nil) {
            print("imageCell: \(userFile[indexPath.row].url)")

            imageCell.viewstoryButton.setTitle("Vis bildeeee - \(self.createdAt[indexPath.row].timeAgo)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            imageCell.viewstoryButton.titleLabel?.textColor  = UIColor.redColor()

            return imageCell
        }
        if (userFile[indexPath.row].url!.rangeOfString(".mp4") != nil) {
            print("videoCell: \(userFile[indexPath.row].url)")

            videoCell.viewstoryButton.setTitle("Vis video - \(self.createdAt[indexPath.row].timeAgo)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            return videoCell
        }
        else{
            print("blankCell")
            return blankCell
        }

    }
```